# How to check if the current user inherits the BYPASSRLS attribute from a role?

Tags: postgresql, roles, row-level-security

I need to check whether row-level-security applies to the `current_user` in a Postgres query. As far as I can tell, I need to check whether the current user is the owner of that table, or has the `BYPASSRLS` attribute, or is member of a role that has this. That [group membership check](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56096/188406) seems cumbersome though, especially considering the `NOINHERIT` attribute of some roles… How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to check whether row-level-security applies to the `current_user`

Indeed there is a much simpler way to check that - in particular for a specific table, which the user (or one of the inherited roles) might be owner of. The solution is to use the [`row_security_active` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-info.html):

> *`row_security_active` checks whether row level security is active for the specified table in the context of the current_user and environment. The table can be specified by name or by OID.*

So just use

```
SELECT row_security_active('schema.table');
```